# Image picker cameraoverlay within the safe area for Iphone x and above not working

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller, safearealayoutguide

I have created s custom UI and assigned it to the camera overlay of UIImagePickerController as below.

Custom View

```
    cameraOverlay = RecordView.loadNib()
    cameraOverlay.frame = UIScreen.main.bounds
    cameraOverlay.buttonStartRecording.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonStartStopRecordingClicked),
                                                 for: .touchUpInside)
    cameraOverlay.buttonCancel.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonCancelClicked), for: .touchUpInside)
    cameraOverlay.buttonSwitchCamera.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonCameraSwitchClicked), for: .touchUpInside)
    
    cameraOverlay.buttonFlash.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonFlashClicked), for: .touchUpInside)
    cameraOverlay.labelTimer.text = "00:00/\(self.secondsToHoursMinutesSeconds(inputSeconds: recordingTimeLimit))"
```

Image Picker Controller

```
    imagePicker.delegate = self
    imagePicker.sourceType = .camera
    imagePicker.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeMovie as String]
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
    imagePicker.cameraOverlayView = cameraOverlay
    imagePicker.showsCameraControls = false
    imagePicker.cameraFlashMode = .off
    imagePicker.cameraCaptureMode = .video
    imagePicker.cameraDevice = .rear
    self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

This works fine with the camera without a notch but UI gets cut from the top behind the notch on iPhone X and above. I somehow need to set my custom overlay within the safe area but not sure how that can be done. Please can someone help me out here. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked whether the phone has a notch

```
  var hasNotch: Bool {
    let bottom = UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window??.safeAreaInsets.bottom ?? 0
    return bottom > 0
}
```

And then handle the Constraints based on that

```
topHeightConstraint.constant = hasNotch ? 94 : 50
instructionBottomConstriant.constant = hasNotch ? 60 : 40
```